# Get insert error code on sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, insert, error-code

How can i run a sql statement on a sqlite database (in android) and get the result of the query? I need to know for sure if the query was executed or not.

I came up with :

```
db.execSQL(sql);
```

but this is a void function.

I get the query_string from a database so i don't know is is a insert or update or delete statement. I know for sure that it will not be a select statement.

Comment: ...and what docs say about `execSQL` ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public String insertQuery(String sql) {
           try{
       db.execSQL(sql);
           }
           catch (SQLException ex){
               return ex.toString();
           }
           return null;
   }
```

Comment: Nice example code, thanks for that after all these years.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [`SQLiteDatabase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html), you can do two things:

**1.)** **Query without result (`UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `DROP`, `ALTER` etc...)**

These queries doesn't return any value, they modify the database. The function to do this is called [`execSQL(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29). You can simply give it an SQL query in string format, and it will execute it.

**2.)** **Query with a result (`SELECT`)**

These queries will return a [`Cursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) object. With a cursor you can iterate on a result set, like you would with any other iterator. The cursor will always 'contain' a single row from the actual resultset, and you can call the move functions to step forward/backward. The function to do this is called [`rawQuery(String, String [])`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29). You can also use the [`query()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) function, using this, you have to type less SQL.

**An example:**

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM yourtable", null);

for(cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext())
{
    /*this means you want to get from the current row a String 
    (CHAR, VARCHAR or TEXT) value from the 0th (first) column*/
    String str = cursor.getString(0);

    /*This means, that you want to get from the current row an 
    integer value from the 1st (second) column*/
    int i = cursor.getInt(1);
    ...
}
```